# synchronizing file names across servers

Tags: python, django, linux, deployment

I have a development & production server and some large video files. The large files need to be renamed. I don't know how to automatically change the file names in the production environment when I change their name in the development environment. I think using git is very inefficient for large files.

On the development environment I copied only the first 5 seconds of the videos. I'll be using Django with South to synchronize the database and git to synchronize the code.

Comment: Hi, Are those files the same on production and on dev? Could you not simply use something like fsync ?

Comment: Maybe a bit overkill for your immediate requirement (but just thought I'd throw the idea in), but have you considered using something like MongoDB and its GridFS then just replicating the servers. If you've effectively got a video streaming site, then you're going to require metadata about stuff anyway and some balancing...

Comment: @Jon Clements will these involve copying everything?

Comment: Yeah, and a bit of a change to how you've probably got things set up - so maybe not a great idea actually - but that would be how I'd go about designing it to start with...

Answer (score 0):

If the names on the development and production server are the same, then record the rename commands in a shell-script.

You can run that on both the development and the production server...